# JavaScript error when importing a package

Tags: javascript, java

getting the following error when importing netscape.javascript

```
importClass(netscape.javascript)
```

**org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "netscape" is not defined.**

Trying to use javascript within applet to get access to cookies.
Using the following as an example to import required package

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/UsingJavaObjectsinJavaScript.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by trial and error.

It seems we need to prefix with **Packages**

```
importPackage(Packages.netscape.javascript);
```